# How to alter view query after exposed filter is changed?

Tags: views, 8, hooks

We have a custom view, `myview`, that has two exposed filters: `country` and `category`. For the `country` value we have a value that we want to be applied regardless of what is selected as the exposed filter that is not `All Countries`.

How would we alter the query after a value is selected so that we always append an `or country = United States of America` to whatever value is selected for the view's query?

**Goal:**

After the exposed filter has been applied, alter the query such that it will return whatever the user selected AND all other nodes where `country = 'United States'`.

Country value:

1. All Countries
2. Worldwide
3. United States of America
4. United Kingdom
5. France
6. Germany

What we were thinking of using [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/8.5.x), but not sure how we can alter the query after a value has been selected.

**mymodule.module**

```
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\QueryPluginBase;

/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 */
function mymodule_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query) {

  if ($view->id() == 'myview') {
    $or_statement = new Condition('OR');
    $or_statement->condition('field_country', '12', '=');
    $query->addWhere(0, $or_statement);
  }

}
```

Current filters:

1. published = yes
2. content type = article
3. country (exposed filter, display all, single select)
4. category (exposed filter, display all, single select)

When using `ksm()` to print the `$condition_group`, this is the results. It is not even showing the two exposed filters. 
[image: condition group]

**Current Where Clause**

`10` is the value selected by the user from the exposed filter and `12` is the one we want to add.

```
WHERE (((node__field_country.field_country_target_id = '10')) AND (node__field_country.field_country_target_id = '12'))
```

**Desired where clause**

```
WHERE (((node__field_country.field_country_target_id = '10')) OR (node__field_country.field_country_target_id = '12'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using d70rr3s suggestion and [this patch (required)](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2559961), I came across this solution that worked.

```
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\QueryPluginBase;

/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 */
function mymodule_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query) {
   if ($view->id() == 'myview'  && !empty($view->exposed_raw_input['field_country']) && $view->exposed_raw_input['field_country'] !== 'all') {
    // Traverse through the 'where' part of the query.
    foreach ($query->where as &$condition_group) {
      foreach ($condition_group['conditions'] as &$condition) {
        if ($condition['field'] == 'your_entity.field_country') {
          $field = 'node__field_country.field_country_target_id';
          $value = 'somevalue';
          $operator = '=';
          $query->addWhere(2, $field, $value, $operator);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

```
WHERE (((node__field_country.field_country_target_id = '10')) OR (node__field_country.field_country_target_id = 'someValue')) AND (node_field_data.status=1) AND (node_field_data.type='article')
```

Filter Criteria where #1 and #2 from screenshot had to be applied:

[image: filter criteria]

Comment: Adding required patch for reference, [ManyToOneHelper ignores group configuration for some cases and forces INNER joins](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2559961)

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the hook example. Assuming your filter name is *field-country* a possible solution could be:

```
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\QueryPluginBase;

/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 */
function mymodule_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query) {
   if ($view->id() == 'myview'  && !empty($view->exposed_raw_input['field_country']) && $view->exposed_raw_input['field_country'] != 'all') {
    // Traverse through the 'where' part of the query.
    foreach ($query->where as &$condition_group) {
      foreach ($condition_group['conditions'] as &$condition) {
        if ($condition['field'] == 'your_entity.field_country') {
           $filter_value = $view->exposed_raw_input['field_country'];
           if (!is_array($filter_value)) {
             $filter_value = [$filter_value];
           }

           $condition = [
             'field' => 'your_entity.field_country',
             'value' => array_merge($filter_value, ['United States Of America']),
             'operator' => 'IN',
           ];
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I haven't fully test it but should work.

Also you can always implement your own [ad-hoc filter plugin](https://www.webomelette.com/creating-custom-views-filter-drupal-8).

**Update**:
Add a condition to check if the filter is multivalue.

**Update**:
Remove strict comparison for filter input value as it may cause side-effects.

Comment: i was writing some `ksm()` statements and found the logic inside the`if` does not run since the condition is not present in the `$condition_group`. I have updated my question to reflect the filters. I am finding it strange that it is not showing in the `$condition_group`

Comment: I am now getting `Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in ns_general_views_query_alter()` when `using array_merge()`. Any thoughts?

Comment: The condition_group won't show if the filter is not present as it is exposed. If I did understand your question you want your extra OR to be added if the filter is present don't you? The error your are getting is because the filter may not be configured to support multiple values so it won't be an array. I'll update my answer to properly handle it both.

Comment: i would like the filter to be added after the user has selected a value for the exposed filter. For example, if the exposed filter is set to "France", i want to return the nodes where `country = france` AND nodes where `country=United States of America`. Essentially always return nodes where `country = United States of America` AND any values selected using the exposed filter.

Comment: i have updated the question with the current where clause.

Comment: The code should output similar results albeit the `WHERE` clause is built using `IN` operator if the subset has 2 elements is basically an `OR`. Further most the code only be executed if the filter is present when the query is being built. Maybe I'm getting lost in translation.

Comment: I did post an answer that was based off of your recommendations and a patch I found. Turns out there was also an issue with the filter groups and operators [see issue 2559961](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2559961)